# ManualUpdate on Excel PivotTable

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007, olap, pivot-table

I'm attemping to update an Excel 2007 pivot table in VSTO (C#) and would like to ensure that the pivot table doesn't get updated until all of my edits are done.  So there's a property on the PivotTable class, ManualUpdate, that apparently does exactly what I want.  Unfortunately it appears that often times when I assign it the value "true" the value doesn't change.  Additionally, I've also seen on other occassions where it will change from "true" to "false" by itself.

BTW, I'm working with an OLAP cube.  Does anyone know what the issue/conditions I need to consider with PivotTable.ManualUpdate?

Thanks!